# c++ implicit type conversion string -> int?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I was just working on c++ types, when i just thought of trying out the following program.

```
void swap(int& a, int& b){
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
    }


int main(){
    string a{"sssss"}, b{"ddddd"};
    swap(a,b); //this should not work!! but it does
    cout << a << ' '<<b <<endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

I was not expecting this to swap the strings, but it does! Why is this working? Although the compiler raises warnings, it is not an error!

Comment: In order to verify that your program indeed does what you think it does, make your `swap` function print a message.

Comment: To improve your question, post the actual code that gives the problem. You have obviously omitted some lines, perhaps thinking they were unimportant.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. That was really helpful. I had not expected the inbuilt swap function to get called. I made it print a message as suggested by @n.m. and that proved that my swap was not being called. I had used "using namespace std" and that is the culprit here. Thanks a lot! Will include the complete code next time. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Assuming the following:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
// or even using namespace std, though this
// would make std::swap a candidate even
// without ADL


// renaming shows that it's not this function
// that gets called ...
void myswap(int& a, int& b) {
  int temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;
  // printing some output also reveals what's going on
}

int main() {
  string a{"sssss"}, b{"ddddd"};
  swap(a,b); // this is not calling your swap!
  // myswap(a,b) produces the error you expected
  cout << a << ' '<< b <<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It's not calling your swap function. Namespaces are kind of interfaces, so when one declares free functions to be in the same namespace as the data types they operate on, then calling them without proper namespace qualification will work.

This is called "argument dependent name lookup", or ADL.

So when you call the function `swap` on a `std::string`, it'll also look for candidates in the `std` namespace. And since there's `std::swap`, which can be applied to strings and no other candidate in your global namespace (since your swap only operates on integers) it'll use it for the call.

---

As I showed above you can make your function produce debugging output or rename it to easily verify that it's not your function that is called.

As a side note: Suppose there were some kind of implicit conversion from string to int. You'd then get two temporaries. Then your swap function would get called (not in reality, since [binding non const references to temporaries isn't allowed](http://ideone.com/IlpDNb)) and these integers exchanged. And then? This wouldn't have any effect on the original strings.

---

Finally, I wouldn't count this code as portable. It only compiles when either the header string or iostream includes the algorithm header, and one of these three provides the specialisation of std::swap for strings. But since this doesn't seem to be guaranteed by the standard, this code would only reliably work when including algorithm yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Your program does not compile. I am guessing that you actually had the following lines but failed to post them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

There is a standard template `std::swap`. Although this is in `#include <algorithm>`, any header may include any other header. So even if you didn't include this specifically, it may have gotten included anyway.

So when you call an unqualified `swap`, both your `swap` and `std::swap` are included in overload resolution.  (Even if you didn't have `using namespace std;`, namespace `std` is still searched because of ADL, since the arguments are of type `std::string` which is in namespace std).

To avoid this happening, you could put your `swap` in a named namespace, and use the qualified name (e.g. `mystuff::swap(a, b);`).